Is it possible to evaluate policies and permissions when obtaining a token with client_credentials grant type in Keycloak
I can get a token with urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket grant type and Keycloak issues the token by evaluating permissions. I want to know that the possibility of obtaining a token with client_credentials grant_type. Is it possible?
